# Read a csv file using FlatFileItemReader, throwing an exception when encountering an empty column

Tags: java, spring-boot, csv, spring-batch

When using the FlatFileItemReader to read a csv file, a column mapping type is Int, but this column is null in the csv file (eg:`6321517,Jack, 1,,` . The last two columns are empty).
An exception(`java.lang.NumberFormatException: Unparseable number`) is thrown when parsing a file

csv

```
CUSTR_NBR,SUR_NAME,CHECK_FLAG,RESN_CODE
6321517,Jack,1,,
```

The first line of data (CUSTR_NBR, SUR_NAME, CHECK_FLAG, RESN_CODE) is parsed at first, so I set `.SetLinesToSkip(1)`. However, the corresponding "CHECK_FLAG" and "RESN_CODE" cannot be performed normally if the null value is parsed. I believe there is a corresponding configuration item. I looked at the documentation for springbatch and couldn't find any related configuration items.

csvItemReader

```java
    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public FlatFileItemReader<InfoDTO> csvItemReader() {
        FlatFileItemReader<InfoDTO> csvItemReader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
        csvItemReader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("data/charge-off.csv"));
        csvItemReader.setLinesToSkip(1);

        DelimitedLineTokenizer tokenizer=new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
        String[] tokens = new String[]{"CUSTR_NBR","SUR_NAME","CHECK_FLAG","RESN_CODE","EMPNO"};
        tokenizer.setNames(tokens);
        DefaultLineMapper<InfoDTO> lineMapper=new DefaultLineMapper<InfoDTO>();
        lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(tokenizer);
        lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(new InfoFileMapper());
        lineMapper.afterPropertiesSet();
        csvItemReader.setLineMapper(lineMapper);

        return csvItemReader;
    }
```

mapper

```
    public class InfoFileMapper implements FieldSetMapper<ChargeOffBatchDTO> {
        @Override
        public InfoDTO mapFieldSet(FieldSet fieldSet) throws BindException {

            if(fieldSet == null){
                return null;
            }

            return new InfoDTO(
                fieldSet.readString("CUSTR_NBR"),
                fieldSet.readString("SUR_NAME"),
                fieldSet.readString("CHECK_FLAG"),
                fieldSet.readInt("RESN_CODE"),
                fieldSet.readInt("EMPNO")
            );
        }
    }
```

I need to map the null column to a value of 0. How to configure？

Comment: Possible duplicate of [spring-batch read in null int values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50020445/spring-batch-read-in-null-int-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not worked with Spring Batch, but looking at the [FieldSet Interface specification](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/transform/FieldSet.html), there seem to be some alternative of ways which you could achieve what you want.

The [Spring Batch reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/htmlsingle/#faultTolerant) does however mention some fault tolerance, specifically around throwing of exceptions, when a value does not exist. In order to disable this you need to set the strict to `false`

```
tokenizer.setStrict(false);
```

Otherwise you could simply try some old fashion alternatives, such as instead of trying to read the value directly into an `int`, just read it into a String and then validate that String before casting it to an `int`

```
String empNo = fieldSet.readString("EMPNO");
if ((empNo == null) || (empNo.equals(""))) {
  empNo = "0";
}
int i = Integer.valueOf(empNo);
```

You may still get a `java.lang.NumberFormatException` if the field is not empty and not a String, so personally I would just solve the problem by handling the exception:

```
int myEmp = 0;
try {
  myEmp = fieldSet.readInt("EMPNO");
} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
  myEmp = 0;
}
```

It's maybe not that eloquent, but it'll work and server the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own line mapper implementation and check for the substring where it is empty and replace it with zero and pass the line forward.